# Filtering JSON objects from array of values

Tags: javascript, performance, json

My code works, but it seems to be running exceptionally slow.

I have an array of values to search, and I have a JSON that I'm filtering.

```
var JSONPull;
var FilterJSON = [];
var TypeIDs = [34,35,36,37,38,39,40,11399,1230,17470,17471,1228,17463,17464,1224,17459,17460,18,17455,17456,1227,17867,17868,20,17452,17453,1226,17448,17449,21,17440,17441,1231,17444,17445,1229,17865,17866,1232,17436,17437,19,17466,17467,1225,17432,17433,1223,17428,17429,22,17425,17426,11396,17869,17870];

fetch('URL API')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
        JSONPull = out;
        TypeIDs.forEach(function (index){
            FilterJSON = JSONPull.filter((element) => {
                console.log("index: "+index);
                console.log(element);
                console.log("type_id: "+ element.type_id);
                element.type_id === index;
            });
        })
    })
```

The console.logs are more just to watch the code while testing, but definitely shouldn't be causing these performance issues.

Thanks in advance for any help/assistance

Comment: logging to console is notoriously slow. If you remove the console.log calls, what's your performance benefit roughly like?

Comment: is `type_id` is unique? or there are duplicates? if it's unique you can use `indexOf` / `includes` to filter. Also after you match an item you can splice the matched `typeID` out of the array. Because with filter you will walk through entire array even after you have a match. So your complexity is O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

You are basically making your object filtering into an \$0(m * n)\$ complexity function ( where \$m\$ is number of type id’s) that your are filtering against and \$n\$ is number of objects in the fetched result set.   This function should only be \$0(n)\$.

To do this, make type id’s into a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which allows \$O(1)\$ lookup and then use this `Set` to filter the fetched objects.

For example:

```
const typeIds = new Set([ /* ids here */ ]);
const isFilteredType = (element) => typeIds.has(element.type);

// and later when filtering results
.then( (out) => out.filter(isFilteredType) );
```

It is also customary in javascript to use lowercase first letter for variable names. Your code would look odd to most JS developer for this reason.

There is really not much of a reason to use `var` in modern JavaScript.  You should primarily use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) being used where the variable needs to be reassignable.

It is not really clear here why `JSONpull` and `FilterJSON` are even needed.